# Confusion on using Web Service using C# + MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf

Hello guys I have a confusing question! If I'm using WCF to create a web service, then I'm trying to connect my service to a database which is a mysql one!

After I have installed the .NET connector, still I can not refer to the database using

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

the client will be adding some sort of ID to the service and I want the WCF app Parse that value and feed it to the database!

I searched on StackOverflow as well and I found these two below to be an approach as well :

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Could this be connecting my service to the database ? Please if you think I have a misunderstanding in the way I want to load the drivers let me know!

THANKS

Comment: Do you get an error when your service tries to connect to the database?

Comment: @Tim yes! Like when I want to type down MySql it underlines it in red and saying that the reference is not there!

Comment: I see you have an answer but I just want to point out that your phrasing would suggest that you don't fully understand what the "using" directive does. If I'm wrong, great, if not have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: Thanks @StephenKennedy , not really that good with db!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you added the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` using statement to your project file(s), but you didn't actually add the DLL to your project.

You can add the DLL to your project by looking in the solution explorer (usually the top-right window in Visual Studio), right-click on References, select Add Reference (**not** Add Service Reference) and then navigate to where you put the MySql drivers.

Adding a using statement only works when the underlying assembly is included in the project's references.

Comment: Ow man! Thanks... I did this yesterday with ASP.net web services to a desktop application, I didn't know that this will need same thing as well!